# how to compare a NSURLconnection http response data with a string value in iphone?

Tags: iphone, string, http, comparison, nsurlconnection

I want to do an activation module which will send a http request with a PIN number and then read the response. If the response is "OK", it opens up with a main menu.  The problem is that I am receiving the response as "OK" but I am unable to compare it with a NSString @"OK".  How to compare the http response with a string?

Here is  my piece of code:

```
-(IBAction) submitPINAction:(id) sender
{
    printf("inside submit btn");
    mydata = [NSMutableData alloc];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest  requestWithURL:
                             [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.100.3/WWTF/activationApp.php?PIN=11111"]
                             
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(connection)
    {
        mydata = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        //Handle error : Not received data
        printf("No internet connection");
    }
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection
   didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData {
    printf("data received");
    if (mydata==nil) {
        mydata =
        [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048];
    }
    [mydata appendData:incrementalData];
    NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:mydata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    
    NSString *string1 = @"OK";
    
    
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    
    if([string1 isEqualToString:temp]){   // HERE IS THE PROBLEM, THE STRINGS ARE NOT GETTIN COMPARED
    
        [prefs setBool:TRUE  forKey: @"activationKey"];
        // show the main menu
        mainMenuController *mmC = [[mainMenuController alloc]initWithNibName:@"mainMenu" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.mmainMenuController = mmC;
        [mmC release];
        [self.view addSubview:[mmainMenuController view]];
    }
    else{
        printf("in else");
        [prefs setBool:FALSE  forKey: @"activationKey"];
        //show an alert
        UIAlertView *alertActivationFail = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Activation Failed!" message:@"PIN is Incorrect" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertActivationFail show];
        [alertActivationFail release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use the following line, to see that the response is actually the OK string, cause it may contain white space or other characters.

```
NSLog(@"string1 = '%@' temp = '%@'", string1, temp);
```

put this line before the if statement like this...

```
NSString *string1 = @"OK";
NSLog(@"string1 = '%@' temp = '%@'", string1, temp);
if([string1 isEqualToString:temp]){   // HERE IS THE PROBLEM, THE STRINGS ARE NOT GETTIN COMPARED
```

If extra whitespace is the reason why the comparison is failing then you can trim whitespace from you string by using the following method:

```
+(NSString *)trim:(NSString *)value {
    return [value stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I would make sure is that you've received all the data before you check for the string. It looks like you do the string checking in `didReceiveData`, but it may make more sense to do the check in `connectionDidFinishLoading` after the data is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Korros and danvin for helping me out.
The problem was indeed with whitespaces.
I trimmed the whitespaces as you said and it worked.

and Thanks stackoverflow.com . It is really a great forum.I find helpful ansers for all iPhone related topics, at the same time it also helps other platform as well i believe.